# how can I "advanced filter" ebay results?

Tags: ebay

When using eBay's search I want to filter all results to find items that would be less than 50 miles away (which is easy to do) but I want to see if they are listed as "pickup only" (which means the items tends to be free or cheaper). Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the "Advanced Search" (link to the right of the search button). Not just the "Advanced Filters" down the left of the listings page.

[image]

In the advanced search you can select "Collection in person" (UK) (or "Local pickup" in US) under delivery options.

[image]